# TransactionManager.DistributedTransactionStarted event is not fired when using SQL Azure database

Tags: .net, transactions, azure-sql-database, distributed-transactions

I need to detect transaction promotion in a big project (I want to log call stacks of those cases). I'm using the `TransactionManager.DistributedTransactionStarted` event to detect such a cases. It works fine on local PC and any on-premise SQL database. However, when connected to the **SQL Azure**, the **event is not fired**!

You can simulate the behavior by running following piece of code:

```cs
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            TransactionManager.DistributedTransactionStarted += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Distributed transaction started!");
            };

            var connectionStrings = new ConnectionStringSettings[]
            {
                new ConnectionStringSettings("Local", "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=True;Database=Test"), 
                new ConnectionStringSettings("Azure", "user id=*****;password=*****;Data Source=***.database.windows.net;Database=Test")
            };

            foreach (var connectionString in connectionStrings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Testing {0}...", connectionString.Name);
                using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Opening first connection to {0}", connectionString.Name);
                    using (var c1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString))
                    {
                        c1.Open();
                        Console.WriteLine("Opening second connection to {0}", connectionString.Name);
                        using (var c2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString))
                        {
                            c2.Open();
                        }
                    }
                    ts.Complete();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("End testing {0}...", connectionString.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

The log produced by the code looks like this:

```text
Testing Local...
Opening first connection to Local
Opening second connection to Local
Distributed transaction started!
End testing Local...
Testing Azure...
Opening first connection to Azure
Opening second connection to Azure
End testing Azure...
```

What makes the difference? Is there any way how to change the behavior (e.g. connection string parameter)? Is there other event I could handle to get notified in both cases?

Tip: from the SQL logs I can confirm that in both cases (on-prem as well as Azure) the transaction *is* promoted, however (to my surprise) the MSDTC service is not involved in case of the SQL Azure database.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be the answer

> On premises, such a scenario usually requires running Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC). Since MSDTC isn't available for Platform-as-a-Service application in Azure, the ability to coordinate distributed transactions has now been directly integrated into SQL Database or SQL Managed Instance.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-transactions-overview

Comment: Anyway, I believe that the `TransactionManager.DistributedTransactionStarted` event should be fired independenty on the coordinator used...